# OpenGL color attachments don't work

Tags: opengl, shaders, deferred-rendering

Trying to implement GBuffer.
Only `gAlbedoSpec` color attachment (GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2) works properly. When i try to use another texture (gPosition or gNormal) in shader, `texture(...)` returns color from glClearColor. It means OpenGL doesn't write data to other color attachments. How to fix it?

GBuffer creation:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

glGenTextures(1, &gPosition);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPosition);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPosition, 0);

glGenTextures(1, &gNormal);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormal);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormal, 0);

glGenTextures(1, &gAlbedoSpec);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAlbedoSpec);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAlbedoSpec, 0);

unsigned int attachments[3] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2 };
glDrawBuffers(3, attachments);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
    std::cout << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

GBuffer using:

```
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glClearColor(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f,1); // gPosition, gNormal is always has this color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // ... rendering objects with GBuffer writing-shader
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    gbuffer_shader->use(); // GBuffer test-rendering shader
    gbuffer_shader->uniformMatrix("projview", ui_mat);
    gbuffer_shader->uniform1i("gPosition", 0);
    gbuffer_shader->uniform1i("gNormal", 1);
    gbuffer_shader->uniform1i("gAlbedoSpec", 2);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAlbedoSpec);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormal);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPosition);

    // ... rendering fullscreen quad with VAO
```

GBuffer writing Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 v_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 v_texCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 v_normal;

out vec4 a_color;
out vec2 a_texCoord;
out vec3 a_normal;
out vec3 a_fragPos;

uniform vec4 u_color;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projview;

void main(){
    mat4 normalMatrix = transpose(inverse(model));
    a_color = u_color;
    a_texCoord = v_texCoord;
    a_normal = (normalMatrix * vec4(v_normal, 1.0f)).xyz;
    a_fragPos = v_position;
    gl_Position = projview * model * vec4(v_position, 1.0);
}
```

GBuffer writing Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 a_color;
in vec2 a_texCoord;
in vec3 a_normal;
in vec3 a_fragPos;

layout (location = 0) out vec3 gPosition;
layout (location = 1) out vec3 gNormal;
layout (location = 2) out vec4 gAlbedoSpec;

uniform sampler2D u_texture0;

void main(){
    gAlbedoSpec.rgb = (a_color * texture(u_texture0, a_texCoord)).rgb;
    gAlbedoSpec.a = 1.0f;
    gPosition = a_fragPos; // doesn't work
    gNormal = normalize(a_normal); // doesn't work
}
```

GBuffer test-rendering Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 v_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 v_texCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec4 v_color;

out vec2 a_texCoord;
out vec4 a_color;

uniform mat4 projview;

void main(){
    a_texCoord = v_texCoord;
    a_color = v_color;
    gl_Position = projview * vec4(v_position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

GBuffer test-rendering Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 a_texCoord;
in vec4 a_color;
out vec4 f_color;

uniform sampler2D gPosition;
uniform sampler2D gNormal;
uniform sampler2D gAlbedoSpec;

void main(){
    f_color = vec4(texture(gPosition, a_texCoord).rgb, 1.0); // returns always initial (glClearColor) color
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by replacing count of color channels of `gPosition` and `gNormal` to 4 (`RGBA16F`) as `gAlbedoSpec`.
Now GBuffer creation:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

glGenTextures(1, &gPosition);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPosition);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPosition, 0);

glGenTextures(1, &gNormal);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormal);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormal, 0);

glGenTextures(1, &gAlbedoSpec);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAlbedoSpec);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAlbedoSpec, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

GLenum attachments[3] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2 };
glDrawBuffers(3, attachments);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
```